# Open separate PR for each occurance of dependency with renovate

Tags: terraform, renovate

I have a repo in which I manage Terraformcode for multiple environments.
For example I would have these files:

```
/terraform/dev/superapp/main.tf
/terraform/prod/superapp/main.tf
```

In those files, I define the used providers, modules, etc. The versions of those components are identical on dev and prod.

I enabled renovate on that repo and it works almost perfectly.

But renovate will open a PR that updates the versions for e.g. the aws provider or the eks-module in dev and prod in just one PR.

But I would like to have separate PRs for each module, provider, etc and then again separate PRs for dev and prod.

So I would end up with four PRs regarding the aws-provider and the eks-module.
One for each dependency in each environment.
I checked the docs of Renovate, but I could not really find out which parameter would trigger such a behaviour, but I am sure this has to be possible.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the configuration option [`additionalBranchPrefix`](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#additionalbranchprefix) to add a prefix to the branch name created by Renovate. By using `parentDir` or `baseDir` in the prefix, Renovate will split PRs based on where the package definition is located.

In your case, since the immediate parent directory has the same name (`superapp`), you would have to use `baseDir` to take into account the whole path of the file to update.

Adding this configuration in `renovate.json` should do the trick:

```
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "managers": ["terraform"],
      "additionalBranchPrefix": "{{baseDir}}-",
      "packagePatterns": [".*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is also a possibility to do this if these two occurrences of the same dependency are in the same `basedir` or even in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is not possible at the moment with renovate.
You could try and include the files/paths one by one, but I do not think that will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).